# extract a table from text

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I wrote the code as follows to extract the table. It is partially working, but there are 2 errors.

- 1- it doesn't capture the last row of data.
- 2- it doesn't capture the value for label if there is any.

Furthermore,

- 3- I also would like to capture the value for missing value if exist

Can you help me to optimize the code?

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {'AG0': ': Age in \n- 2 -Value Label Unweighted\nFrequency%\n42- 367 11.1 %\n43- 421 12.7 %\n44- 416 12.6 %\n45- 389 11.8 %\n46- 400 12.1 %\n47- 392 11.9 %\n48- 299 9.1 %\n49- 255 7.7 %\n50- 168 5.1 %\n51- 115 3.5 %\n52- 71 2.2 %\n53- 40.1 %\n Missing Data   \n.- 50.2 %\n Total 3,302 100%\nBased upon 3,297 valid cases out of 3,302 total cases.\n•Mean: 45.85\n•Median: 46.00\n•Mode: 43.00\n•Minimum: 42.00\n•Maximum: 53.00\n•Standard Deviation: 2.69\nLocation: 9-10 (width: 2; decimal: 0)\nVariable Type:  numeric \n'}

import re
import pandas as pd

# Extract table from string
pattern = r'(\d+)-\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s*%'
table_data = re.findall(pattern, data['AG0'])

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(table_data, columns=['Value', 'Unweighted Frequency',"%"])

# Print DataFrame
print(df)
```

output:

```
   Value Unweighted Frequency     %
0     42                  367  11.1
1     43                  421  12.7
2     44                  416  12.6
3     45                  389  11.8
4     46                  400  12.1
5     47                  392  11.9
6     48                  299   9.1
7     49                  255   7.7
8     50                  168   5.1
9     51                  115   3.5
10    52                   71   2.2
```

Update:
how can I make the code above work for this text, which has labels?

```
 data2 = {'PRE': ': Currently ?\nAre you currently ?\nValue Label Unweighted\nFrequency%\n1No 3295 99.8 %\n2Yes 00.0 %\n Missing Data   \n-9Missing 70.2 %\n Total 3,302 100%\nBased upon 3,295 valid cases out of 3,302 total cases.\n•Minimum: 1.00\n•Maximum: 1.00\nLocation: 11-12 (width: 2; decimal: 0)\nVariable Type:  numeric \n- 3 -(Range of) Missing Values:  -9 , -8 , -7 , -1\n',}
```

Update :
how can I make the code above work for this text, in which the labels contain spaces?

```
 data3 ={'F3': 'aempted\nBld  aepted?\nValue Label Unweighted\nFrequency%\n1Yes, as per protocol 2745 83.1 %\n2Yes, menses too variable 91 2.8 %\n- 5 -Value Label Unweighted\nFrequency%\n3Yes, Last attempt 405 12.3 %\n4No, Not fasting and/or not in window 10.0 %\n Missing Data   \n-9Missing 16 0.5 %\n-1N/A 20.1 %\n.- 42 1.3 %\n Total 3,302 100%\nBased upon 3,242 valid cases out of 3,302 total cases.\n•Minimum: 1.00\n•Maximum: 4.00\nLocation: 21-22 (width: 2; decimal: 0)\nVariable Type:  numeric \n(Range of) Missing Values:  -9 , -8 , -7 , -1 , .\n'}
```

Update:

The way I extract a pdf to text.

```
def read_pdfs(dictionary):
#     dfs_names_text_dic = {}
    for pdf_file, name in dictionary.items():
        pdfFileObj = open(pdf_file, 'rb')
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdfFileObj)
        output = []
        for i in range(3,2000):
            pageObj = pdfReader.pages[i]
            output.append(pageObj.extract_text())
#         dfs_names_text_dic[name] = output
        pdfFileObj.close()
    return output
```

Comment: The last row of data is missing the value (and is dubious, since the total is already 99.8%, so probably 100% if you take rounding into account). As for the label, it would be hard to include it in the regex without at least an example!

Comment: I added another data with label, thanks a lot

Comment: yes exactly. I need a code that satisfies both text data2  and data, and I am really stuck on that, any help is appriciated

Comment: My expected output would have the header of  ['Value', 'Label', 'Unweighted Frequency', '%']  in a data frame and captures all the values

Comment: All of these issue that I am facing is because I first tried with tabula but it doesn't capture the table from pdf correctly sometime, for example if a table span in 2 page, it will be counted as 2 different table.

Comment: Hey: this pattern seems to solve your 1st 2 points; test it and let me know (I must go for a while, but I'll gladly explain it later if needed): `pattern = r'\n(\d+)([^ ]+)(?:\s+(\d*))?\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s*%'`  ; in short, I made the capture group for 'value' optional.

Comment: Yes it does! it was a big help thanks

Comment: Swifty again a big thanks, I just updated another data called data3, there is string instead of numbers for values, how we can modify this regex that satisfies all of these 3 dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following RegEx to collect named capture groups that you can easily process later, excluding the label if it's `None` or including it if a valid value exists.

```py
import re

data = {'AG0': ': Age in \n- 2 -Value Label Unweighted\nFrequency%\n42- 367 11.1 %\n43- 421 12.7 %\n44- 416 12.6 %\n45- 389 11.8 %\n46- 400 12.1 %\n47- 392 11.9 %\n48- 299 9.1 %\n49- 255 7.7 %\n50- 168 5.1 %\n51- 115 3.5 %\n52- 71 2.2 %\n53- 40.1 %\n Missing Data   \n.- 50.2 %\n Total 3,302 100%\nBased upon 3,297 valid cases out of 3,302 total cases.\n•Mean: 45.85\n•Median: 46.00\n•Mode: 43.00\n•Minimum: 42.00\n•Maximum: 53.00\n•Standard Deviation: 2.69\nLocation: 9-10 (width: 2; decimal: 0)\nVariable Type:  numeric \n'}

pattern = r'(?P<value>\d+)-?(?P<label>\S+)?\s+(?P<frequency>\d+)\s+(?P<percent>\d+\.\d+)\s*%'

groups = [ m.groupdict() for line in data.get('AG0').split(sep='\n') if (m := re.match(pattern, line)) ]
groups
```

Result:

```py
[{'value': '42', 'label': None, 'frequency': '367', 'percent': '11.1'},
 {'value': '43', 'label': None, 'frequency': '421', 'percent': '12.7'},
 {'value': '44', 'label': None, 'frequency': '416', 'percent': '12.6'},
 {'value': '45', 'label': None, 'frequency': '389', 'percent': '11.8'},
 {'value': '46', 'label': None, 'frequency': '400', 'percent': '12.1'},
 {'value': '47', 'label': None, 'frequency': '392', 'percent': '11.9'},
 {'value': '48', 'label': None, 'frequency': '299', 'percent': '9.1'},
 {'value': '49', 'label': None, 'frequency': '255', 'percent': '7.7'},
 {'value': '50', 'label': None, 'frequency': '168', 'percent': '5.1'},
 {'value': '51', 'label': None, 'frequency': '115', 'percent': '3.5'},
 {'value': '52', 'label': None, 'frequency': '71', 'percent': '2.2'}]
```

Second data dictionary example:

```py
import re

pattern = r'(?P<value>\d+)-?(?P<label>\S+)?\s+(?:(?P<frequency>\d+)\s+)?(?P<percent>\d+\.\d+)\s*%'

data2 = {'PRE': ': Currently ?\nAre you currently pregnant?\nValue Label Unweighted\nFrequency%\n1No 3295 99.8 %\n2Yes 00.0 %\n Missing Data   \n-9Missing 70.2 %\n Total 3,302 100%\nBased upon 3,295 valid cases out of 3,302 total cases.\n•Minimum: 1.00\n•Maximum: 1.00\nLocation: 11-12 (width: 2; decimal: 0)\nVariable Type:  numeric \n- 3 -(Range of) Missing Values:  -9 , -8 , -7 , -1\n',}

groups2 = [ m.groupdict() for line in data2.get('PRE').split(sep='\n') if (m := re.match(pattern, line)) ]

groups2
```

Result:

```py
[{'value': '1', 'label': 'No', 'frequency': '3295', 'percent': '99.8'},
 {'value': '2', 'label': 'Yes', 'frequency': None, 'percent': '00.0'}]
```

There is a small difference between the first and second RegEx that you may wish to use for both examples.  I excluded in the first example, because as @Swifty mentioned, the record for value 53 looked suspicious.

`(?:(?P<frequency>\d+)\s+)?`

[EDIT]
Based on the third data dictionary that you provided, there will have to be a small modification made to the RegEx:

`(?P<label>\D+)`

Third example:

```py
data3 ={'F3': 'Blood draw attempted\nBlood draw attempted?\nValue Label Unweighted\nFrequency%\n1Yes, as per protocol 2745 83.1 %\n2Yes, menses too variable 91 2.8 %\n- 5 -Value Label Unweighted\nFrequency%\n3Yes, Last attempt 405 12.3 %\n4No, Not fasting and/or not in window 10.0 %\n Missing Data \n-9Missing 16 0.5 %\n-1N/A 20.1 %\n.- 42 1.3 %\n Total 3,302 100%\nBased upon 3,242 valid cases out of 3,302 total cases.\n•Minimum: 1.00\n•Maximum: 4.00\nLocation: 21-22 (width: 2; decimal: 0)\nVariable Type: numeric \n(Range of) Missing Values: -9 , -8 , -7 , -1 , .\n'}

pattern = r'(?P<value>\d+)-?(?P<label>\D+)?\s+(?:(?P<frequency>\d+)\s+)?(?P<percent>\d+\.\d+)\s*%'

groups3 = [ m.groupdict() for line in data3.get('F3').split(sep='\n') if (m := re.match(pattern, line)) ]

groups3
```

Output:

```py
[{'value': '1',
  'label': 'Yes, as per protocol',
  'frequency': '2745',
  'percent': '83.1'},
 {'value': '2',
  'label': 'Yes, menses too variable',
  'frequency': '91',
  'percent': '2.8'},
 {'value': '3',
  'label': 'Yes, Last attempt',
  'frequency': '405',
  'percent': '12.3'},
 {'value': '4',
  'label': 'No, Not fasting and/or not in window',
  'frequency': None,
  'percent': '10.0'}]
```

I should note, though, that this will only work so long as there is no numeric data held within the label.  If there is, then even this third RegEx will fail.

Comment: Thanks a lot Will also the code works for data3 ? it is the last update of question

Comment: Thank you looking more closely I need a regex that satisfies 3 of data, data2 and data3 .... as I have a huge dictionary with many data, I need regex that satisfies them once , Can I only have one regex for 3 of data?

Comment: You'll have to test or fix the formatting of the third data dictionary so that it's valid Python.  ;)

Comment: the third data in the question is a valid python.. isnt it?

Comment: No, there are some missing quotation characters.  I think I cleaned it up, though.  I'll edit my answer as there is a small modification that must be made to the RegEx.

Comment: If I can have one regex for 3 dataset would be perfect, because I have a dictionary of many data set.

Comment: Updated answer.  However, carefully review your data, because the percentage for value 4 in the third data set is suspect.

Comment: Thanks a lot The problem is I  have a dictionary with many key and values and it is huge, I dont know how to perform each of these 3 regex on the data, do you think it is possible to have only one regex? or any other solution you might have?

Comment: The third RegEx example I provided works for all three of the use cases you provided.

Comment: when I run on first and second data >>AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Did you change the key `'F3'` to `'AG0'` and `'PRE'` respectively ?

Comment: Make sure you are also updating the name of the dictionary in each case, since you use `data` and `data2` between your examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot Philip and Swifty ! there is just a small thing that I notice, maybe you can help me to fix, I am not very good with regex. 

for this data :

previously?\nValue Label Unweighted\nFrequency%\n1No 752 22.8 %\n2Yes 10.0 %\n Missing Data   \n.- 2549 77.2 %\n Total 3,302 100%\nBased upon 753 valid cases out of 3,302 total cases.

I know its problem pypdf2 that the this part  n2Yes 10.0 %\n looks like this, but there actually this should be like this   n2Yes 1 0.0 %\ and 1 goes to value and  0.0 goes under %

any idea on that?

Comment: I noticed it happens always for 1 digit number, once value is one digit number, in the text it is follows by % number without space.  but in real they are two different number.

Comment: I also update in the question how do I extract pdf file.

Comment: I also created another question for this problem

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76179475/extract-pdf-using-pypdf2-doesnt-correctly-extract-numbers

Comment: Also I notice that it doesn't capture the number  under value correctly, if we have : Height (in cm)\nValue Label Unweighted\nFrequency%\n140.50- 10.0 %\n141.00- 10.0 %\n, it capture 40 and 41 instead of 140.50 and 141.00