# Extract pdf using pypdf2 doesn't correctly extract numbers

Tags: python, nlp, pypdf

I wrote the function as follows to extract the pdf file to text using pypdf2.
Pdf has a lot of table that pypdf2 doesn't capture it correctly for example
it captures the text such as :

> sugar?\nValue Label Unweighted\nFrequency%\n1- 40.1 %\n2- 10 0.3 %\n-
> 24 -Value Label Unweighted\nFrequency%\n3- 60.2 %\n4- 40.1 %\

It concatenate number under Value and number under %  when I have 1 digit number under Value.

The correct text extraction should be like this

> sugar?\nValue Label Unweighted\nFrequency%\n1- 4 0.1 %\n2- 10 0.3 %\n-
> 24 -Value Label Unweighted\nFrequency%\n3- 6 0.2 %\n4- 4 0.1 %\

How can I fix this issue?

```
def read_pdfs(dictionary):
#     dfs_names_text_dic = {}
    for pdf_file, name in dictionary.items():
        pdfFileObj = open(pdf_file, 'rb')
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdfFileObj)
        output = []
        for i in range(3,2000):
            pageObj = pdfReader.pages[i]
            output.append(pageObj.extract_text())
#         dfs_names_text_dic[name] = output
        pdfFileObj.close()
    return output
```

Comment: This may be related to PDF fonts, or you can try some other packages such as: PyMupdf

Comment: what is the difference of  PyMupdf and pypdf2

Comment: pdfplumber usually offers better results with its [`.extract_text(layout=True)`](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber#extracting-text) - the data looks like a "table" though, have you tried table extraction?

Comment: I tried but table extraction from tabula for example is not correctly capture tables for example if I have one table span in 2 page, it capture it as a 2 different table while it is one table.

Comment: Yeah, that's tricky. With `pdfplumber`, it has `.find_tables` which gives you the `.bbox` coords. If there is no new "table header" on the page, you can check if the left/right coords match the last table from the previous page. That's one way people attempt to detect multi-page tables and combine them. As for text, `.extract_text(layout=True)` should keep the "columns" in the text, which may be a workable approach.

Comment: `PyPDF2` is deprecated. Use `pypdf`.

Comment: If you don't share the PDF, nobody can give a good answer to your question.